# Login User in Membership Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

i use membership Asp.Net in website. but I do not want use Login control. I have this Code and controls in login page:

```
Username: <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
Password: <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Login_Click" />
```

and:

```
protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //Check Username and password

      //Login User   
   }
```

please help me for write login code user in membership Asp.Net.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. What have you tried, and where have you run into a problem you can't solve?

Comment: Is that ALL you have tried so far? We don't even know the schema for whatever database you're using to store login info - and that's if you are using a database at all, and not a file somewhere or the web.config (or a big hack - I've seen people using the Cache to store credentials, because *"unlike a database it cannot be copied by hackers"*).

Comment: Why not use the Login control?

Comment: i use database membership asp.net ,... but I do not want use Login control

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if username exists in your list of accounts.  If it does, check if the passwords match.  If they do, store the user's name or ID in the session container (Which will be used throughout your website to identify the user's account).  If you are using a database, make sure it's not vulnerable against [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) attacks.